# Configure Google Analytics Funnel Steps For Dynamic Pages

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to figure out how to setup Google analytics funnels to use page steps that have a dynamic tail.  I have tried using the regex with a * for the wildcard but still not luck.  Here is my configuration:

[image]

The result is an empty funnel:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to prove that the step tracking works for the goal page and for the non-dynamic step (`/checkout`)? The reason I ask is because I think what you're doing should work and I'm wondering if something else is wrong.

Comment: @AndrewChart This recommendation below works flawlessly

Answer (score 3):

`-` is a special character in regular expressions

Try these instead:

- `/order\-complete`
- `/travel\-blog/.*`